# python-polars string concatenation of two existing columns

Tags: python-polars

I want to concatenate the last letter from two existing columns and create a new column from this using polars.LazyFrame

for example in pandas can achieve this with the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["abc","def"], "col2":["ghi","jkl"]})
df["last_letters_concat"]=df["col1"].str.strip().str[-1]+df["col2"].str.strip().str[-1]
print(df)
```

My attempt in polars

```
import polars as pl
from polars import col
#using same df

df.lazy().with_column(
    (pl.col("col1")[-1] + pl.col('col2'))[-1].alias("last_letters_concat")).collect()
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str.slice` expression for that. Below I show to examples that produce the same result.

```py
pl.DataFrame({
    "col1": ["abc","def"], 
    "col2":["ghi","jkl"]
})

# concat all last letters
out1 = df.select(
    pl.concat_str([pl.col("col1").str.slice(-1), pl.col("col2").str.slice(-1)])
)

# concat only two specific columns
out2 = df.select(
    pl.col("col1").str.slice(-1) + pl.col("col2").str.slice(-1)
)

assert out1.frame_equal(out2)
print(out1)
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌──────┐
│ col1 │
│ ---  │
│ str  │
╞══════╡
│ ci   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ fl   │
└──────┘
```

I recommend using the `concat_str` expression as this has `O(n)` complexity where `n` is the number of columns you add, whereas the addition operator has `O(n^2)` complexity.

*EDIT: as of `polars >= 0.14.12` the optimizer will ensure it always is linear complexity*